# How to output excel files with multiple urls in one cell with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

One of my dataframe element contains text in html format : `This is <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a> and this is <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>`

I want to save this dataframe in excel file.

Can the excel file show the string as `This is google and this is yahoo` with two urls in one cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"text": ['This is <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a> and this is <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>']})

df["links"] = df.text.apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'<a href="(.+?)".+?', x))
df.text = df.text.str.replace(r"<a.+?>(.+?)</a>", r'\1', regex=True)
print(df)
#                               text                                            links
#0  This is google and this is yahoo  [https://www.google.com, https://www.yahoo.com]
```

Comment: Followed by df.to_excel() probably

Comment: Thank you, Anwarvic. However, I want to produce the effect: when I export ``df`` by ``df.to_excel``, that cell in excel will contain 2 clickable urls in one cell.